# What is TurtleBot Interactive Markers's Fixed Frame?

Tags: ros, frame, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In [TurtleBot Interactive Markers Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQ6fNrehMNI&feature=player_embedded), its TurtleBot Interactive Markers's Fixed Frame is /odom.

But my rviz should set to /base_link that I can show the whole robot of Turtlebot.

[image: image description]

Why they are different?

Thank you~

---

Here I set to /odom topic which failed to interact:

[image: image description]

Here is set to /base_link:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30836/what-is-turtlebot-interactive-markers%27s-fixed-frame?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you set the fixed frame to /odom, you will see the robot move around in the world (on your screen). This can be useful, as you can visually register where the robot is based on the grid pattern. If you set it to /base_link, you'll have a harder time figuring out how the robot is moving.

It shouldn't make a difference to Interactive Markers functioning, but you'll probably find that it's easier to drive if you set to /odom.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-04-02**:
I tried to change to /odom,but I failed to use the interact function. I have revised the original post.